# Minimal polynomial over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I have some troubles with this exercise:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be the following elements of $\mathbb{Q}(T)$:
>   $a:=T^3+T$ and $b:=T^2 -2$
>   Compute the minimalpolynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a)$, and use the answer to find a nonzero polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Q}[X_1,X_2]$ such that $f(a,b)=0$

Now the first question would be isn't $\mathbb{Q}(T^3+T)=\mathbb{Q}(T)$ true, because I can work with $T$ as a basis and therefore I can build $a$ and $b$? Or do the elements in $\mathbb{Q}(T^3+T)$ look like this: $1,(T^3+T),(T^3+T)^2...$?
Now over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ this would be $X-T^2+2$, but I'm a little confused about $\mathbb{Q}(T^3+T)$. Also I guess $f$ would be $f:X_1-T^3+T +X_2-T^2+2$ only if $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}[X_1,X_2]$ but I don't know if they are elements of it...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $T$ is transcendental over $\Bbb{Q}$, so there is no way to write it using powers of $T^3+T$. The elements of $\Bbb{Q}(T^3+T)$ are quotients $a(T^3+T)/b(T^3+T)$, where $a$ and $b$ are polynomials with rational coeffcients. The elements $1, T^3+T, (T^3+T)^2,\ldots$ only span the ring $D=\Bbb{Q}[T^3+T]$. The field $\Bbb{Q}(T^3+T)$ is the field of fractions of $D$.

Comment: Because $T$ is a zero of the polynomial $x^3+x-a\in\Bbb{Q}(a)[x]$ we see that $[\Bbb{Q}(T):\Bbb{Q}(a)]=3$. Also $b\in\Bbb{Q}(T)$, so the minimal polynomial can be cubic at wors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments we have every reason to look for a cubic minimal polynomial. So we begin by calculating
$$
b^2=T^4-4T^2+4,\qquad b^3=T^6-6T^4+12T^2-8.
$$
We want to write some linear combination of powers of $b$ in terms of powers of $a$. As the highest power of $T$ occurring above was $T^6$ it is natural to suspect that we only need $a$ and $a^2=T^6+2T^4+T^2$. This suggests that we look for a linear combination of $b^3$ and $b^2$ that matches with the degree $6$ and $4$ terms of $a^2$. Such a combination is
$$
b^3+8b^2=T^6+2T^4-4T^2+24=a^2-5T^2+24.
$$
I'm sure that you can find constants $c_1,c_2\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that $c_1b+c_2=5T^2-24$. This gives you the solution 
$$b^3+8b^2+c_1b+(c_2-a^2)=0.$$

---

The resulting polynomial is surely irreducible. The minimal polynomial cannot be a quadratic as $[\Bbb{Q}(T):\Bbb{Q}(a)]=3$ and cannot contain a quadratic intermediate field. The minimal polynomial cannot be linear for then $b\in\Bbb{Q}(a)$. As $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)=\Bbb{Q(T)}$ this would imply that $T\in \Bbb{Q}(a)$ violating transcendence of $T$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: And for completeness, we need some argument to show the polynomial truly is irreducible.

Comment: @Hurkyl You are, of course, correct in askinf this to be explained in an answer. At first I was planning the answer to be a hint only - relying somewhat on my comments under the OP. When I converted it to an answer, I had forgotten about the need to include these points. Appreciate the reminder.

Comment: Another remark I want to make is that the end result looks like a polynomial defining an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form: $P(b)=a^2$ with a cubic polynomial $P(x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$. Unfortunately that cannot be. IOW the polynomial $P(x)$ must have multiple zeros. This is because $a=T^3+T$, $b=T^2-2$ gives a rational parametrization to the resulting curve. And a curve with a rational parametrization necessarily has genus zero, so cannot be elliptic.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. I'm still struggling a little bit to understand the whole thing. I understand the steps till the linear combination. We want to express with $b^3 + 8b^2$ a polynomial that is equal to another polynomial with $a$ as basis. Is that correct? $(a^2 - 5T^2 + 24.$) But how do I interpret $5T^2 + 24$, I can not make this expression through powers of a. Also I don't get which now represents the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a)$. Thank you.

Comment: @Matriz You want to find a polynomial $f \in \Bbb{Q}(a)[T]$ say $f(T) = d_0 + d_1 T + d_2 T^2 + \cdots + d_n T^n$ such that $f(b)=0$. You have $a^2=T^6+2T^4+T^2$ and you know that you want to subtract some elements expressed with respect to $b$ such that you get $0$. For instance $a^2$ has degree $6$ so you begin by subtracting $b^3$, which has also degree $3$. You get $a^2-b^3 = 8T^4 -11T^2 +8$. Now you want to subtract something of degree $4$ with leading coefficient $8$, so you subtract $8b^2$ and you get $21T^2 -24$, and so on.

Comment: @Matriz When you are evaluating $f(b)$ you are actually evaluating something like this: $d_0 + d_1 b + d_2b^2 +\cdots + d_n b^n$. Remember that $d_i \in \Bbb{Q}(a)$ so for instance you can take $d_0 = a^2 + \text{constant}$ and then subtract all the $b$, with the help of the coefficients $d_1,d_2,...$, that you found before :).